# Hamburger menu showing up on desktop device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple navbar using bootstrap 4 and BEM methodology, when I run my app the hamburger menu is displayed in desktop device instead of being hidden.

Here is the link to the jsfiddle: [Bem Navbar menu](https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/rjysf257/10/)

HTML

```
  <nav class="main-nav">
      <div class="main-nav__logo">
        <li class="main-nav__link">
          <a>Majeni</a>
        </li>
      </div>
      <button class="main-nav__toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="main-nav__icon navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="main-nav__collapse collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="main-nav__list ml-auto">
          <li class="main-nav__item--active">
            <a class="main-nav__link" href="#">Home
              <span class="main-nav__current sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a class="main-nav__link" href="#">About us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a class="main-nav__link" href="#">What we do</a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a class="main-nav__link " href="#">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item">
              <a class="main-nav__link " href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

css

```
   .main-nav {
        background-color: green;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: stretch;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        &__item{
                padding: 0 2em;
                background-color: #088887;
                display: flex ;
                align-items: center;
            }
        &__link{
            list-style-type: none;
            list-style: none;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong in my codes? any help suggestion , please correct me if anything am doing it wrongly way. thank

Comment: All I see are classes that aren't declared anywhere, nothing telling at what width this Navbar is supposed to collapse, I'm not even sure where Bootstrap is taking part in this mess since you aren't using any of it's classes except `.collapse` and some aligning. You should check the [Navbar documentation for Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a responsive class so that it would be hidden / visible on the devices that you want.

If you want it visible only on "xs" screens you would add the following classes:

```
.d-block .d-sm-none
```

Here's an updated JSFiddle ( You may have to expand the window to see it disappear ) - https://jsfiddle.net/rjysf257/14/

Pulled from the Bootstrap 4 documentation:

Hiding elements
For faster mobile-friendly development, use responsive display classes for showing and hiding elements by device. Avoid creating entirely different versions of the same site, instead hide element responsively for each screen size.

To hide elements simply use the .d-none class or one of the .d-{sm,md,lg,xl}-none classes for any responsive screen variation.

To show an element only on a given interval of screen sizes you can combine one .d-*-none class with a .d-*-* class, for example .d-none .d-md-block .d-xl-none will hide the element for all screen sizes except on medium and large devices.

**Screen Size:**    Class

**Hidden on all:**  .d-none

**Hidden only on xs:**  .d-none .d-sm-block

**Hidden only on sm:**  .d-sm-none .d-md-block

**Hidden only on md:**  .d-md-none .d-lg-block

**Hidden only on lg:**  .d-lg-none .d-xl-block

**Hidden only on xl:**  .d-xl-none

**Visible on all:** .d-block

**Visible only on xs:** .d-block .d-sm-none

**Visible only on sm:** .d-none .d-sm-block .d-md-none

**Visible only on md:** .d-none .d-md-block .d-lg-none

**Visible only on lg:** .d-none .d-lg-block .d-xl-none

**Visible only on xl:** .d-none .d-xl-block

[Bootstrap 4.0 Utilities: Display ( Hiding Elements )](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)